# LinkButton not accessing EventArg

Tags: linkbutton, eventargs

I am using c#.net.

I am trying to create a LinkButton within the code-behind, when I debug my code I recieve no errors, however its not accessing the EventArg attached to the button, it does however refresh the page. What am I doing wrong?

Button Code

```
LinkButton myLinkButton = new LinkButton();
myLinkButton.ID = appointment.appID.ToString();
myLinkButton.CommandArgument = appointment.appID.ToString();
myLinkButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(ViewClick);
myLinkButton.CommandName = appointment.appID.ToString();
myLinkButton.Text = appointment.contactName
```

Used to style button

```
string divLook = "height:" + divHeight + "em";
```

Button is then added to a panel

```
Panel p = new Panel();
p.Style.Add("linkStyle", divLook);
p.CssClass = "standardLink";
p.Controls.Add(myLinkButton);
dataCell.Controls.Add(p);  



protected void ViewClick(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
      var appointmentId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      Debug.Write("Are you even getting in here");
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Clare

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks legit.  I would recommend viewing the source of the generated page and looking at the ID that the link button is getting.  It may be duped on the page.

Comment: This is what it is outputting to screen: 
<a id="ctl00_BodyContent_14" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$BodyContent$14','')">1 1 (Triple Birth)</a>
<a id="ctl00_BodyContent_15" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$BodyContent$15','')">Add Forename Add Surname (Single Birth by Declaration )</a>

Comment: Make sure your web.config has <compilation debug="true"> and when you run the project that run with debugging is enabled.  Also, set a breakpoint in the PageLoad methods to ensure debugging is working as intended.